# A relation in a finite ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, finite-rings

Let $R$ be a finite ring such that for any $a,b\in R$ there exists $c\in R$ (depending on $a$ and $b$) such that $a^2+b^2=c^2$.

Prove that for any $a,b,c\in R$ there exists  $d\in R$ such that $2abc=d^2$.

Comment: this question is being down-voted by some people - may I get to know why? unfortunatelly none of them dared to leave a comment...

Comment: You've just copied a problem (and not a very interesting one) out of a textbook. There's no indication about what we should help you with, what part of the problem you don't understand, or what you've covered previously in the class this is homework from. You've just dumped a problem here and asked someone to solve it for you. We're all happy to help out--- that's the point of this site--- but we're not going to do it for you.

Comment: do you mean "Prove that for any a,b,c , such $c^2=b^2+a^2, \exists d ...$ ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the word "assumption" to refer to the statement: "for any $a, b\in R$
there exists $c\in R$ (depending on $a$ and $b$) such that $a^2+b^2=c^2$". Let the phrase ``desired conclusion'' refer to the statement: "for any $a, b, c\in R$ there exists $d\in R$ such that $2abc=d^2$".

The assumption implies that the set of squares is closed under sum. This implies that if $u$ is a square, then $u+u=2u$ is a square, and 
$u+2u=3u$ is a square, etc, until $-u$ is a square (by finiteness). 
It follows from this that $(x+1)^2 + (-x^2) + (-1) = 2x$ is a square for any $x$, which is the desired conclusion when $x=abc$.